# Is it possible to have certain words in the document always in bold?

Tags: bold

I am writing an AWK programming book and when I explain things, I refer to special AWK variables all the time, such as `ORS`. Is it possible to set LaTeX up in such a way that these words are always in bold in the text, so I don't have to write `\bf{ORS}` all the time?

Comment: if these words do not exist as normal words in your document, then use search and replace with an external editor. ORS=>\texttt{ORS}. It is common to write program sequences in typewriter format.

Comment: The question seems pretty similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15626/highlight-language-keywords-in-a-paragraph (which is still unanswered, though)

Comment: Related Question: [Possible CSS type features?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76348/possible-css-type-features).  Although it may not be useful for entire documents, or large blocks of text.

Answer (score 28):

For a job like this I usually define a convenience macro:

```
\def\<#1>{\textbf{#1}}
```

Now you can say `\<ORS>` without much overhead and still don't need to define macros for all the terms that are special. In the context of a book you might want to think about how this macro can be also used to create an index. (This is a little trickier and might warrant a separate question.)

Comment: @Christian According to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) isn't it better to use a `/newcommand` instead?

Comment: @pmav99 I believe you cannot use `\newcommand` to define a macro that uses TeX's pattern matching capabilities that I've used here to make the macro easier to use than regular macros.

Comment: Oh I got it now. You are using `def` because it allows you to use different delimiters. EDIT we wrote together.

Comment: @Christian Why add two characters to the typing of the command, what is the advantage of typing `\<OFS>` to `\OFS`?

Comment: @Yiannis Sure, but for that gain you have to define commands upfront (using whatever method). `\<OFS>` provides a tradeoff between defining command `\OFS` upfront  and using `\textbf{OFS}` within the text. I am too lazy to maintain commands like `\OFS` but I can see why one would like it.

Comment: @Christian But then I would rather ...`\def\*#1 {\textbf{#1}}` closer to markdown.

Comment: @Yiannis This would preclude writing `variable \*OFS, \*NF, and ...` because the space to terminate the argument would be missing. I'd say, this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @pmav99 the `xparse` package allows you to have the flexibility of arbitrary pattern matching in delimiters with the safety of `\newcommand`

Comment: @Seamus Thank you. Would you care to provide an example?

Answer (score 12):

In lieu of a ton of `\newcommands`, I would rather define a macro that stores a number of words for which you require them to be bold. This is simply a comma delimited list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\boldcommandlist{\@elt FS,\@elt OFS,\@elt RS,\@elt ORS,\@elt NR,\@elt NF,\@elt FNR,}
\def\@elt#1,{%
 \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\textbf{#1}\xspace}
}
\boldcommandlist

Awk \OFS is an output equivalent of awk \FS variable. 
By default awk OFS is a single space character.
Following is an awk \OFS example. Use the command \OFS.

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The `\boldcommandlist` holds the words to be typeset in bold:

```
 \boldcommandlist{FS,OFS,...}
```

You can always add another one if you wish at a later stage.

The `\@elt` is short for an element and is initially undefined. When we give it a definition, it picks up its argument as the next word (delimited by a comma) and creates a command for it.
The `xspace` is a small package that correctly adjusts the spacing after a command catering correctly for such things as punctuation.

Comment: \makeatother changes the @ back to a symbol (category code 'other').

Answer (score 9):

With LuaTeX, you can translate your input before it is passed on to TeX. Here is an example of doing the automatic translation in ConTeXt:

```
\usemodule[translate]

% Notice the space before the words
\translateinput [ OFS][ \bold{OFS}]
\translateinput [ FS] [ \bold{FS}]

\enableinputtranslation

\starttext
Awk OFS is an output equivalent of awk FS variable. 
By default awk OFS is a single space character.
Following is an awk OFS example. Use the command OFS.

\stoptext
```

Comment: Does it work when `OFS` is at the beginning of a line in the source?

Comment: @Andrey. No :( The translate module translates all strings, so if I use `\translate[OFS][...]` even something like \startOFS will be translated. It should be possible to write a more intelligent pattern to check if the surrounding characters are non-letters and only do the substitution.

Comment: @Aditya, I can't find any documentation for `translate`.  (Actually, I always get confused navigating `ConTeXt` documentation in general, which I think says more about me than about `ConTeXt`.)  Does it accept a regular expression to match, or only literal text?

Comment: @LSpice: My understanding is that it was designed to show a proof of concept. It accepts only a literal match, but generalizing to regular expressions should not be difficult. It is just a [10 line function](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/:/tex/context/base/m-translate.mkiv) with some boilerplate code.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, try to avoid `\bf{}`, use `\textbf{}` instead. More info [here](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex03-LaTexUsage/ar01s02.html), or search for the [New Font Selection Scheme](http://tinyurl.com/6fnplrl)

you could use `\newcommand{\ORS}{\textbf{ORS}\xspace}` at the preamble, and invoke it in your document with `\ORS`. For `\xspace` usage look at the link in the comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\ORS}{\textbf{ORS}\xspace}

\begin{document}
Compare \ORS with ORS.

Sentence ending in \ORS.
\end{document}
```

### Update

Updated the answer according to lockstep's suggestion.

Comment: By including a trailing space in your definition of `\ORS`, this macro can't be used before punctuation marks. Better approaches are a) using the `xspace` package b) using "delimited macros" -- see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/1103#1103) for details.

Comment: @lockstep Cool! I didn't know about xspace, although I knew that there must be a way to do it!

Answer (score 7):

Combining Christian's answer with Yiannis, you can get a single `\<...>` markup which expands to different things (bold, italics,...) depending on the argument. It might be useful in some cases where you have different types of words to highlight.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% used for an example.

\def\<#1>{\csname keyword@@#1\endcsname}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{\expandafter\doaux\expandafter{\keyword@style{#1}}{#1}}
\def\doaux#1#2{\global\@namedef{keyword@@#2}{#1}}   
\def\keyword@style#1{\textbf{#1}}
\do{FS}
\do{OFS}
\do{RS}
\do{ORS}
\do{NR}
\do{NF}
\do{FNR}
\def\keyword@style#1{#1\footnote{From the \<python> language.}}
\do{try}
\do{raise}
\def\keyword@style#1{\href{http://www.#1.org/}{#1}}
\do{python}
\do{CTAN}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
I don't know what \<OFS> is, nor \<RS>, but they seem to be parts 
of the awk language. On the other hand, I know a little bit about 
\<try> and \<raise>. There are many packages about \TeX\ on the
\<CTAN> website.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is really slick! +1

Comment: @Christian. The number of extra characters to type could be reduced from 3 (`\<`, `>`) to 1 (an active character of your choice), but this would mean parsing the word one letter at a time until a non-letter is seens. Not too hard, but a little slower.

Comment: Knuth used `|OFS|` in the TeXbook by making `|` active and IMHO he does not rely on parsing letter by letter.  Still two extra characters but I'd find the symmetry attractive.

Comment: @Christian. You are right, it is definitely simpler and faster to use two characters.