# How to redefine \d within classicthesis?

Tags: classicthesis

For some unknown reason the following produces an error in classicthesis:

```
% at the beginning of classicthesis-config.tex
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathbf{d}}

\begin{document}
$\d$
\end{document}
```

The error says \d is invalid in math mode and $ is missing. It doesn't occur with a simple test case, for sure it's related to the template settings.

Comment: are you using `hyperref`?  i think `hyperref` redefines `\d`, so all bets would be off.

Comment: Hopefully, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19111/10679) question helps. In particular, the point is that `\d` is already defined in the latex kernel. And, in this case, to make things complicated, as @barbara points out, hyperref redefines `\d` to be `\PD1-cmd \d \PD1\d` from `\OT1-cmd \d \OT1\d`. In particular, however, note that, just this example (together with `\documentclass{...}`) *will* compile. :-)

Comment: I'd simply use a different name: `\newcommand{\bd}{\mathbf{d}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just put the redefinition in the document so after classicthesis and/or hyperref have defined it, but if you don't want to do that

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\d}{\mathbf{d}}}
```

Probably works (although untested as no example supplied).

Comment: This works perfectly well, just added it in my file. +1