# Vertical space between tables vspace won't work

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have 2 tables, one above the other. At the moment I can't make any space between them in my report. The strange thing is I moved them in to a new blank document with all the same preamble and `\vspace` worked. I don't really know what the problem is but it's frustrating that they are stuck together. My tables are within a subsection of a section. My preamble and table code are below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}        % only needed if you include TpX drawings
\usepackage{graphicx} % only needed if you include graphics files other than TpX
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\newcommand{\by}{\bf y} 
\newcommand{\bx}{\bf X} 
\newcommand{\T}{\text{T}} 


\newcommand{\bb}[1]{{\bf#1}}
\newcommand{\bo}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{{\mathbb E}\left[ #1 \right]}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{{\mathbb {V}}\left(#1 \right)}

\newcommand{\ssc}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
}%
\item[]}{\end{list}}

\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% to get subsubsections in toc

\let\oldtocsection=\tocsection

\let\oldtocsubsection=\tocsubsection

\let\oldtocsubsubsection=\tocsubsubsection

\renewcommand{\tocsection}[2]{\hspace{0em}\oldtocsection{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[2]{\hspace{1em}\oldtocsubsection{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsubsection}[2]{\hspace{2em}\oldtocsubsubsection{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{MCMC mixing results for the MH within Gibbs sampler} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
     \bb{Response}: & \bb{ESS} (\%) & \bb{Acceptance rate} (\%) \\ \hline
     \bb{TST} & 100.0 & 52.90 \\
     \bb{WASO} & 99.90 & 56.68  \\
     \bb{N2} & 98.56 & 50.23 \\
     \bb{R} & 99.33 & 63.19  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\label{mix} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\vspace*{10mm}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{MCMC mixing results for the strongest and weakest models for benchmark $g$ for response \bb{TST}.} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
     \bb{Model}: & \bb{ESS} (\%) & \bb{Acceptance rate} (\%) \\ \hline
     Strongest & 87.04 & 69.3 \\
     Weakest & 6.74 & 10.9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\label{mix2} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem.  Actually, I couldn't run it at all (emergency stop).

Comment: Your example document compiles fine for me and produces space between the tables.  It still works okay when I had sections and subsections and surrounding text.  Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem, e.g. using the `lipsum` package to fill out with some text.

Comment: The lipsum package wouldn't work for some reason. I tried taking the section out of my report in to a seperate tex file and it worked fine. It's only as part of my report that I get a problem. I have got round it by using \clearpage to move them on to a new page and then vspace works.

Comment: Sorry about earlier, I missed the "\end{document}" when I made the copy.  You could try replacing the \vspace{10mm} with a \rule{1pt}{10mm}.  Maybe it is showing up somewhere else in your document.

Comment: `table`s are floating environments, so it doesn't really make sense to add space between them, they can move away from where the space is added.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. An answer?

Comment: @egreg Done. (... to get over 15 characters)

Answer (score 4):

`table` is a floating environment, meaning that LaTeX can move it around, e.g. to avoid getting a large blank space at the end of page, if the table doesn't fit (for more details on how that works, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)). For that reason, adding a `\vspace` between two `table` environments doesn't really make sense, as the they can move away from that space.

If the two tables should be placed just after one another, you can place both `tabular`s in the same `table` environment, and add the `\vspace` between them, inside the `table`. See code below.

Some other comments:

- Be careful when using one-letter macro names, several of these are defined already, see [Short names for macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros)
- Note that the `\it`, `\bf`, etc. font macros are deprecated because
  they do not use the new font selection scheme introduced with LaTeX2e.
  Please use `{\itshape ..}`, `{\bfseries ..}` or `\textit{..}`, `\textbf{..}` instead.
  See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
  and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)
  for more information.
- Generally, I don't think you should use just `h!` as a float specifier. That limits where LaTeX can place the floats.
- If you ask egreg, he'll tell you that both `\left( ... \right)` and `\ensuremath` are usually bad ideas. See ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses) (and linked questions) for some discussion about the former, and [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro) about the latter.
- As the `table` environment (and all other environments, I think) form a group, it is not really necessary to use `\bgroup`/`\egroup` to limit the effect of the `\arraystretch` I think.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{MCMC mixing results for the MH within Gibbs sampler} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
     \bb{Response}: & \bb{ESS} (\%) & \bb{Acceptance rate} (\%) \\ \hline
     \bb{TST} & 100.0 & 52.90 \\
     \bb{WASO} & 99.90 & 56.68  \\
     \bb{N2} & 98.56 & 50.23 \\
     \bb{R} & 99.33 & 63.19  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}

\caption{MCMC mixing results for the strongest and weakest models for benchmark $g$ for response \bb{TST}.} % title of Table
\begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
     \bb{Model}: & \bb{ESS} (\%) & \bb{Acceptance rate} (\%) \\ \hline
     Strongest & 87.04 & 69.3 \\
     Weakest & 6.74 & 10.9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{mix2} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put both tabulars into *one* `table` environment. Then your `\vspace` works. Everything inside of `table` is local, there is no need for grouping its contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\newcommand{\by}{\bf y} 
\newcommand{\bx}{\bf X} 
\newcommand{\T}{\text{T}} 
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{{\bf#1}}
\newcommand{\bo}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{{\mathbb E}\left[ #1 \right]}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{{\mathbb {V}}\left(#1 \right)}
\newcommand{\ssc}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{MCMC mixing results for the MH within Gibbs sampler} % title of Table
\label{mix} % is used to refer this table in the text
\centering % used for centering table
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
     \bb{Response}: & \bb{ESS} (\%) & \bb{Acceptance rate} (\%) \\ \hline
     \bb{TST} & 100.0 & 52.90 \\
     \bb{WASO} & 99.90 & 56.68  \\
     \bb{N2} & 98.56 & 50.23 \\
     \bb{R} & 99.33 & 63.19  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{10mm}
\caption{MCMC mixing results for the strongest and weakest models for benchmark $g$ for response \bb{TST}.} % title of Table
\label{mix2} % is used to refer this table in the text
\begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
     \bb{Model}: & \bb{ESS} (\%) & \bb{Acceptance rate} (\%) \\ \hline
     Strongest & 87.04 & 69.3 \\
     Weakest & 6.74 & 10.9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a grumpy old man, but is it really necessary to add an answer that doesn't add anything new compared to the existing one?

Comment: While the existing response was more informative, I found this response a bit more concise as the first sentence of the provides the answer. Useful for people looking for a fast resolution during time-restricted work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\Floatbarrier` after the first table (i.e. after you finish the first table with `\end{table}`) so that the float property which was creating the problem can be restricted and then add `\vspace` between two tables. It worked for me.