# Creating shortcode

Tags: algorithms

I have a document in LaTeX in which I have to use a lot of code over and over again. Is it possible to define this code somewhere with a shortcut so that I can call it up by only using the shortcut in the real code? I also want to be able to use it in all environments.

An example to make my question more understandable:

- repeated code: `acbdbad`
- shortcut: `\a`
- Real code:  `dakjmdka \a dkqjdk \a dqksjf \a`

Is there also a name for this? This is probably something quite straightforward but I'm new to Latex and I have no idea what it is called, so it's hard to find on the web.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example? In some cases, it will depend on what you're trying to repeat.  If it's just text: `\newcommand\a{acbdbad}`

Comment: You basically want `\newcommand\myshortcut{abcdbad}`, but as Sean says it may depend on the use case. Edit: How does algorithms come into this, by the way?

Comment: @SeanAllred There is a bunch of single letter macros defined by default, including `\a`, so some care should be taken. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know that, but I was trying to keep the correlation in the example OP provided; yours luckily maintains clarity while setting a good example, but I guess it's good to mention this to OP.

Comment: @SeanAllred Ah, ok. I thought I should mention it as your example will generate an error.