# Is it safe to "renewcommand" \SS? (Which packages use \SS command?)

Tags: macros, packages

I've tried to set

```
\newcommand{\SS}{\mathcal{S}}
```

in the preamble but I've discovered that this command is already defined.

So, I tried native command on my code and I've found that it is a "simple" double S.

Now, I can fix my problem using

```
\renewcommand{\SS}{\mathcal{S}}
```

but I'm not sure it is safe (I don't know if `\SS` is used by LaTeX only to draw a (simple or special) double S, or for something else too).

Does someone know if it is safe (or when it isn't safe) to do a “renewcommand” of `\SS`?

Comment: `\SS` is used for the uppercase version of the German symbol ß, usually rendered as "SS".

Comment: And what about the name `\cS`, as calligraphic S? In standard LaTeX it is not defined.

Comment: thank you @PrzemysławScherwentke for suggest! You are right! :-)

Comment: Not really safe: your bibliographic data might contain a `ß` that in turn might be capitalized: the final result would be at least puzzling.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, that is a danger I didn't mind! I definitely choose \cS command, as suggested by PrzemysławScherwentke

Comment: See also [Short names for macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the safety of re-defining command `\SS` (which is the capital of "ß") in order to shorten the command `\mathcal{S}`, @egreg said:

> "Not really safe: your bibliographic data might contain a ß that in turn might be capitalized: the final result would be at least puzzling."

That is definitely true, so I've decided to follow the suggestion given by @PrzemysławScherwentke:

> "And what about the name `\cS`, as calligraphic S? In standard LaTeX it is not defined."

In fact `\cS` command, as is shown by @LaRiFaRi (and by `\show\cS`), is safe:

> ```
> \cS=undefined.
> l.6 \show\cS
> ```

Thank you all: I change my code from `\renewcommand{\SS}{\mathcal{S}}` to `\newcommand{\cS}{\mathcal{S}}`.

Corrado.

Comment: `\mathcal{S}` surely has some specific meaning in you document? Maybe a macro name reflecting that meaning would be the best choice altogether...

Comment: Mainly I've used \cB (ex \BB) for a "basis of a topology" and \cS for a "sub-basis", but in some other places of my thesis i've used \mathcal{S} (or \mathcal{B}) for other "general but locally-special" sets, so I've prefered a neutral name for these commands (instead of \mathcal{N}, wich I have named \baire, according with your suggestion).

Comment: Personally I'd prefer `\newcommand*\basis[1]{\mathcal{#1}}` and `\newcommand*\subbasis[1]{\mathcal{#1}}` and then maybe `\newcommand*\sbS{\subbasis{S}}` or using `\subbasis{S}` directly, similar for other meanings... :) I like it if my source reflects what I *mean* not what it *looks like* when typeset.

Comment: I'm not "stable" in such opinion yet... in some moment I agree with you and set beautifull and meaningfull code...but a moment later I think: "I can only write \mathcal{S}...is it necessary to create a macro?!...and three macros?!" sometimes my answer is yes, someothers is no :-)

Comment: Old thread. For what it's worth, I use \cA for \mathcal{A}, \bA for \mathbb{A}, \fA for \mathfrak{A}. It's short, extensible, and easy to remember from project to project. I don't think long macro names you'll use all the time are sustainable, even if they preserve semantic meaning.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to see, what a command is used for, you can use the `\show` macro:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
%\show\cS
\show\SS
\end{document}
```

This will show:

> ```
> \SS=macro:
> ->\T1-cmd \SS \T1\SS .
> l.7 \show\SS
> ```

Ok, this information is not so cool, but you can see that is has something to do with the T1 encoding and you see that it is used as a macro. Googling the same macro will easily result in the definition (the German upper-case sz-letter). The command `\cS` as recommended in the comments results in:

> ```
> \cS=undefined.
> l.6 \show\cS
> ```

and thus is safe to be used.

Comment: You can do `\expandafter\show\csname T1\string\SS\endcsname` or also ``texdef -t latex -p[T1]fontenc T1\\SS`` from the command line, which would reveal that `\SS` ultimately does `\char"DF` (slot `"DF`=223 in the T1 encoded fonts indeed contains an “SS” glyph).

Comment: Thanks, you may add that to my answer if you want. Still, [this](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=latex+\SS) is kind of easier... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't safe.

\SS may come from a transformation of \ss (lowercase ß) to uppercase in a running headline. When you redefine it, and by bad chance a German sharp s is in your chapter or section title, the running headline may have an unexpected look. Followup errors like "missing $ inserted" may occur too, depending on your re-definition of \SS.