# Keep position of coordinates with different axis-scale

Tags: pgfplots

How can I keep the position of a coordinate when I use it in another environment with a different axis-scale?

In the example, I would like the `\node [...] at (c);` in the right picture to be in the position of the red point instead of scaling the y-coordinate with the axis-scale.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0, y=0]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1
]
\node (c) at (0.6,0.8){};
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=white,draw] at (c) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0, y=0]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=10
]
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=white,draw] at (c) {};
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,red] at (0.6,0.8) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way is to just define a macro for the coordinate and reuse it:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand*{\SpecialPoint}{0.6,0.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0, y=0]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1
]

\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=white,draw] at (\SpecialPoint) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0, y=0]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=10
]
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=blue,draw,overlay] at (\SpecialPoint) {};
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,red] at (0.6,0.8) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok that helps for my defined points, thanks a lot. I have also points calculated with `intersections`. Is there a way to do the same with those? (Sorry for not mentioning that in the `minimal` I tried to keep it as short as possible.)

Comment: @kash: You should be able to adapt a solution from [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz). I will try to look into that tomorrow, but in case you were in a rush thought I'd give you a pointer for now.

Comment: Yes that was what I was trying to adapt already before, but it didn't work out. Now I tried it again and at least found out that `\pgfgetlastxy` does not seem to work out when you use axis with `\usepackage{pgfplots)`.

Comment: Well, I use a workaround now (I just keep the axis-scale the same in both pictures now). Maybe I try to find a solution for the problem above later. Thanks you for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

You should define the point outside of all axes to be independent of the axis used. Since `(c)` is a coordinate, you can simply define it by `\def\Pointc{0.6,0.8}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\def\Pointc{0.6,0.8}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0, y=0]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1
]
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=white,draw] at (\Pointc) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0, y=0]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=10
]
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=blue,draw] at (\Pointc) {};
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,red] at (0.6,0.8) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Careful about redefining one letter macros such as `\c`, [many of them are used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19112/586). With `\def` you will not even be told that you're overwriting an existing macro, while with `\newcommand` you will.

Comment: Yes, we are better off naming it `\Pointc`, for example, I edited my answer. I just wanted to give the OP the basic idea. Since `Pointc` is not a command but a coordinate, I will never declare it by `\newcommand`. Besides, I never used those single-letter macros in a document (especially in English).