# Add caption to pie-chart with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, charts

I am having a problem to add a caption to a pie chart that I made with tikz. 
Do you know where is the error?

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,fourier,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\degre}{$^\circ$}

\colorlet{color0}{blue!40}
\colorlet{color1}{orange!60}
\colorlet{color2}{DarkGreen!40}
\colorlet{color3}{yellow!60}
\colorlet{color4}{red!60}
\colorlet{color5}{blue!60!cyan!60}
\colorlet{color6}{cyan!60!yellow!60}
\colorlet{color7}{red!60!cyan!60}
\colorlet{color8}{red!60!blue!60}
\colorlet{color9}{orange!60!cyan!60}


\makeatletter
    \tikzset{%
        dc tag/.style={align=center},
        dc legend/.style={align=left,anchor=west},
        dc sector/.style={fill=\Cj,line join=round}
        }

    \pgfkeys{/DiagCirc/.cd,
        % liste of \Name/Value
        value list/.store in=\Value@list,
        % circular : 360 - semi circular 180
        angle max/.store in=\Angle@max,
        angle max=360,
        % radius of the diagram
        radius/.store in=\R@dius,
        radius=4cm,
        % composition of the legend
        % \V value
        % \N name
        % \P percent
        % \A angle
        % \Cj color
        legend/.store in=\L@gend,
        legend=,
        % location of the legend
        legend location/.store in=\Legend@Loc,
        legend location={($(\R@dius,\R@dius)+(.5,-.5)$)},   
        % poisition of the node in the sector
        % 0 center, 1 on the edge, 1.++ external
        factor/.store in=\F@ctor,
        factor=.80,
        % composition of the node in the sector
        tags/.store in=\T@gs,
        tags=,
        % correction of round errors in percents
        percent corr/.store in=\C@rrP,
        percent corr=,
        % correction of round errors in angles
        angle corr/.store in=\C@rrA,
        angle corr=,
        % individual shift
        shift sector/.store in=\Shift@j,
        shift sector=,
        % more nodes in the sectors, or new legeng
        sup loop/.store in=\Sup@Loop,
        sup loop=,
        % code of the diagram
        diagram/.code={%
        % Calculation of the sum
        \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{0}
        \foreach \i/\y in \Value@list {\xdef\S@m{\S@m+\i}}  
        \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{\S@m}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\C@eff{\Angle@max/\S@m}

        % beginning of the first sector
        \xdef\@ngleA{0}

        % main loop
        \foreach \V/\N [count=\j from 0] in \Value@list {%

        % calculation of the current angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\A{\V*\C@eff}

        % superior limit of the sector
        \pgfmathsetmacro\@ngleB{\@ngleA+\A} ;

        % mean angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\MedA{(\@ngleA+\@ngleB)/2} ;        

        % color
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\@k{mod(\j,10)}
        \def\Cj{color\@k}

        % individual shift
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\Shift@j}{}}{%
        \edef\Sh@ft{0}}{%
        \pgfmathparse{array({\Shift@j},\j)}
        \edef\Sh@ft{\pgfmathresult} 
        }

        % drawing of the sector
        \draw[dc sector,shift={(\MedA:\Sh@ft)}] (0,0)
            -- (\@ngleA:\R@dius) arc (\@ngleA:\@ngleB:\R@dius)
                node[midway] (DC\j) {} -- cycle ;

        % low limit of the next sector
        \xdef\@ngleA{\@ngleB} ;

        % current percent correction
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{round(\V/\S@m*100)}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\C@rrP}{}}{}{%
            \pgfmathparse{array({\C@rrP},\j)}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{\P+\pgfmathresult}
        }
        \edef\P{\P\,\%}

        % current angle and corection
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{round(\A)}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\C@rrA}{}}{}{%
            \pgfmathparse{array({\C@rrA},\j)}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{\A+\pgfmathresult}  
            \edef\A{\A\,\degre}
        }

        % the sector node
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\T@gs}{}}{}{%
        \DiagNode[dc tag]{\F@ctor} {\T@gs} ;
        }

        % the legend
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\L@gend}{}}{}{%
        \begin{scope}[shift=\Legend@Loc]
        \draw[fill=\Cj] (0,-.5*\j)
                rectangle ++(.25,.25) ++(0,-.15)
                node[dc legend] {\strut\L@gend} ;
        \end{scope}
        }

        % some more stuff
        \Sup@Loop ;
        }

        } % end of diagram code
    }
\makeatother

% Node on the \j sector
\newcommand{\DiagNode}[2][]{\node[#1] at ($(0,0)!#2!(DC\j)$)}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[%
    % style options
    dc tag/.append style={font=\bfseries\small},
    % diagram options
    /DiagCirc/.cd,
    value list={13.8/Motor vehicles,16.6/Aerospace,19.9/Industrial\slash business,13.1/Consumer products\slash electronics, 12.2/Medical\slash dental, 10.5/Academic institutions,5.9/Government\slash military, 3.1/Architectural, 4.9/Other},
    angle max=360,             % circular
    factor=.87,
    tags=\N\\\P,                   % custom sector nodes
    diagram] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: for caption you need add after your image and before `\end{figure}` a `\caption{...} \label{fig:pie}` ...

Comment: @Zarko The code generates an error, I think that is the focus of the question.

Comment: The error is caused by the `\N\\\P`. By the way, have you considered using `pgf-pie`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., then the title of question is wrong formulated. also the tags are misleading.

Comment: @Zarko True. Hopefully Alexis can clarify.

Comment: I tried to use pgf-pie and I can't make it work as well. 
How's the error linked with \N\\\P? should I just remove it?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. By the way yes the code formulate an error if you add the environment figure and try to create a caption as is described in my question

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't realized that it the code actually works without the `figure` environment (it wasn't easy to understand from the question alone). You can't remove `\N\\P` though, as that is what prints the labels in the diagram.

Comment: Note that it also works if you say `tags=\N\P`, so it seems the linebreak disturbs things for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explanation here, because I don't know why the error occurs, but I can present a possible workaround. Albeit a not very elegant one.

First, specify a `text width` in the `dc tag` style, e.g.

```
dc tag/.style={align=center,text width=5cm},
```

Then in the actual `tikzpicture`, modify the `tags` line to read

```
tags=\hfill\N\hfill{} \newline\PP
```

Using `\newline` instead of `\\` removes the error, but when `text width` is not set, it doesn't do anything, that's why I added `text width` as said above. However, for some reason the first line in a node will not be centered even with `align=center`, that's the reason for the `\hfill`s. (I reported this at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/403/.)

The `text width` does have the side effect of adding some whitespace in the `tikzpicture` because the nodes are wider than the text. To get around that you can add

```
\useasboundingbox (0,0) circle[radius=4cm];
```

immediately after `\begin{tikzpicture}`, `4cm` is the radius of the pie chart.

You will also see that I changed `\P` to `\PP`. The reason for that is found in [Short names for macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros). As you can see `\P` is already used. I don't know if the `\edef\P..` actually would cause problems, but I don't think it hurts to avoid those used macro names.

All that said, it is often recommended to not use pie charts at all, so I added a quick example of a bar chart in addition, just for the fun of it.

Complete code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier,ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\degre}{$^\circ$}

\colorlet{color0}{blue!40}
\colorlet{color1}{orange!60}
\colorlet{color2}{DarkGreen!40}
\colorlet{color3}{yellow!60}
\colorlet{color4}{red!60}
\colorlet{color5}{blue!60!cyan!60}
\colorlet{color6}{cyan!60!yellow!60}
\colorlet{color7}{red!60!cyan!60}
\colorlet{color8}{red!60!blue!60}
\colorlet{color9}{orange!60!cyan!60}


\makeatletter
    \tikzset{%
        dc tag/.style={align=center,text width=5cm},
        dc legend/.style={align=left,anchor=west},
        dc sector/.style={fill=\Cj,line join=round}
        }

    \pgfkeys{/DiagCirc/.cd,
        % liste of \Name/Value
        value list/.store in=\Value@list,
        % circular : 360 - semi circular 180
        angle max/.store in=\Angle@max,
        angle max=360,
        % radius of the diagram
        radius/.store in=\R@dius,
        radius=4cm,
        % composition of the legend
        % \V value
        % \N name
        % \P percent
        % \A angle
        % \Cj color
        legend/.store in=\L@gend,
        legend=,
        % location of the legend
        legend location/.store in=\Legend@Loc,
        legend location={($(\R@dius,\R@dius)+(.5,-.5)$)},   
        % poisition of the node in the sector
        % 0 center, 1 on the edge, 1.++ external
        factor/.store in=\F@ctor,
        factor=.80,
        % composition of the node in the sector
        tags/.store in=\T@gs,
        tags=,
        % correction of round errors in percents
        percent corr/.store in=\C@rrP,
        percent corr=,
        % correction of round errors in angles
        angle corr/.store in=\C@rrA,
        angle corr=,
        % individual shift
        shift sector/.store in=\Shift@j,
        shift sector=,
        % more nodes in the sectors, or new legeng
        sup loop/.store in=\Sup@Loop,
        sup loop=,
        % code of the diagram
        diagram/.code={%
        % Calculation of the sum
        \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{0}
        \foreach \i/\y in \Value@list {\xdef\S@m{\S@m+\i}}  
        \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{\S@m}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\C@eff{\Angle@max/\S@m}

        % beginning of the first sector
        \xdef\@ngleA{0}

        % main loop
        \foreach \V/\N [count=\j from 0] in \Value@list {%

        % calculation of the current angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\A{\V*\C@eff}

        % superior limit of the sector
        \pgfmathsetmacro\@ngleB{\@ngleA+\A} ;

        % mean angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\MedA{(\@ngleA+\@ngleB)/2} ;        

        % color
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\@k{mod(\j,10)}
        \def\Cj{color\@k}

        % individual shift
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\Shift@j}{}}{%
        \edef\Sh@ft{0}}{%
        \pgfmathparse{array({\Shift@j},\j)}
        \edef\Sh@ft{\pgfmathresult} 
        }

        % drawing of the sector
        \draw[dc sector,shift={(\MedA:\Sh@ft)}] (0,0)
            -- (\@ngleA:\R@dius) arc (\@ngleA:\@ngleB:\R@dius)
                node[midway] (DC\j) {} -- cycle ;

        % low limit of the next sector
        \xdef\@ngleA{\@ngleB} ;

        % current percent correction
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\PP{round(\V/\S@m*100)}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\C@rrP}{}}{}{%
            \pgfmathparse{array({\C@rrP},\j)}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\PP{\PP+\pgfmathresult}
        }
        \edef\PP{\PP\,\%}

        % current angle and corection
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{round(\A)}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\C@rrA}{}}{}{%
            \pgfmathparse{array({\C@rrA},\j)}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{\A+\pgfmathresult}  
            \edef\A{\A\,\degre}
        }

        % the sector node
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\T@gs}{}}{}{%
        \DiagNode[dc tag]{\F@ctor} {\T@gs} ;
        }

        % the legend
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\L@gend}{}}{}{%
        \begin{scope}[shift=\Legend@Loc]
        \draw[fill=\Cj] (0,-.5*\j)
                rectangle ++(.25,.25) ++(0,-.15)
                node[dc legend] {\strut\L@gend} ;
        \end{scope}
        }

        % some more stuff
        \Sup@Loop ;
        }

        } % end of diagram code
    }
\makeatother

% Node on the \j sector
\newcommand{\DiagNode}[2][]{\node[#1] at ($(0,0)!#2!(DC\j)$)}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,0) circle[radius=4cm];
\path[%
    % style options
    dc tag/.append style={font=\bfseries\small},
    % diagram options
    /DiagCirc/.cd,
    value list={13.8/Motor vehicles,16.6/Aerospace,19.9/Industrial\slash business,13.1/Consumer products\slash electronics, 12.2/Medical\slash dental, 10.5/Academic institutions,5.9/Government\slash military, 3.1/Architectural, 4.9/Other},
    angle max=360,             % circular
    factor=.87,
    tags=\hfill\N\hfill{} \newline\PP,                   % custom sector nodes
    diagram] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{A type of chart that it is generally recommended not to use}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Motor vehicles, 13.8
Aerospace, 16.6
Industrial/business, 19.9
Consumer products/electronics, 13.1
Medical/dental, 12.2
Academic institutions, 10.5
Government/military, 5.9
Architectural, 3.1
Other, 4.9
}\piedata
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
yticklabels from table={\piedata}{[index]0},
ytick=data,
axis lines=left,
xmin=0,
enlarge y limits,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
]
\addplot table[x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\piedata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Perhaps a bar chart?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```