# Fitting Plot onto TikZ Coordinate Plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, domain

I am trying to create simple worksheets where students either: (a) see a randomly generated linear graph and must determine the equation or (b) are given a randomly generated linear equation and must plot the line.

How do I make the graph stay on the given portion of the plane? i.e. from -10 to 10 for both x and y.

Is there some "easy" way to do it, or do I have to use a formula that relates the randomly generated slope `\m` and y-intercept `\b` to an appropriate domain or range?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\LinearEquation}
{%
%slope
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{int(random(0,8)-4)}%

%y-intercept
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(random(0,8)-4)}%

% Linear Equation
\(y={\m}x+\b\)
}
\LinearEquation


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
\draw[red, very thick, , range=-10:10, <->] plot (\x,\m*\x+\b); %this did not work
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the arrow tips for the line, just add `\clip  (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);` before you `plot`. And in the options for the plot, you want `domain`, not `range`.

Note also that `\b` is already defined (see [Short names for macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros)), so it's best to avoid using it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\LinearEquation}
{%
%slope
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Slope}{int(random(0,8)-4)}%

%y-intercept
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Intercept}{int(random(0,8)-4)}%

% Linear Equation
\(y={\Slope}x+\Intercept\)
}

\begin{document}
\LinearEquation

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
\clip  (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
\draw[red, very thick, , domain=-10:10] plot (\x,\Slope*\x+\intercept); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Everything in one macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\LinearEquation}
{%
%slope
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Slope}{int(random(0,8)-4)}%
%y-intercept
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Intercept}{int(random(0,8)-4)}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
\node [above right] at (-10,10) {\(y={\Slope}x+\Intercept\)};
\draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
\clip  (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
\draw[red, very thick, , domain=-10:10] plot (\x,\Slope*\x+\Intercept); 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\LinearEquation
\LinearEquation

\LinearEquation
\LinearEquation

\LinearEquation
\LinearEquation

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get to this. The solution is working out perfectly. Thanks!