# TikZ way to define several constants with just one macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using `TikZ` to plot several things (geometric surfaces, line plots, etc.) in just one environment. These plots depend on several constants that I define in the same `tikzpicture` environment. This is a (dummy) example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1}
\def\g{0.5}
\def\kamax{5}
\def\M{15}
\def\T{3}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ra}{1 + \a*\M^(1-\g)/\kamax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Rb}{1 + \a*\M^(1-\g)/(4*\kamax)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\la}{\M/(2*\T*\Ra)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lb}{\M/(2*\T*\Rb)}

\begin{axis}[domain=0:\M/\T, xlabel = Rate of consumption, ylabel = Time of purchase, title = Optimal time to purchase, legend pos=north west, axis equal image]
\addplot[color=blue][domain=0:\la] {0};
\addplot[color=blue][domain=\la:\lb] {2*\T - (sqrt(2*\a*\kamax*\M^(1+\g)*\T*\x*(\M-2*\T*\x)))/(\a*\M*\x)};
\addplot[color=blue][domain=\lb:\M/\T] {\T};
\addplot[color=red] coordinates {(\la,0)(\la,\T)};
\addplot[color=red] coordinates {(\lb,0)(\lb,\T)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the example, the constants defined with `\def` are the "essential" constants of the problem I'm studying, and those defined with `\pgfmathsetmacro` are needed to make the plotting easier.

After plotting the example exposed before, I would like to change some of the values of the "essential" constants and plot the same five plots again (in the same environment) to compare results. My question is: is there a way to create macro or function that takes as input my "essential" constants and returns as output the other constants?

My objective is purely to simplify the `.tex` reading; if I redefine the constants in the same environment after plotting the `.tex` compiles just fine.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Put the calls to `\pgfmathsetmacro` in a macro (via `\newcommand`) and call this macro when you have change your "essential" constants.

Comment: You have 5 plots in your example, but they are not really 'plotting again'. They are plotting different things ....

Comment: I edited both the MWE and the question, clarifying what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just pack the code into a macro like this

```
\newcommand*{\a}{}
\newcommand*{\g}{}
\newcommand*{\kamax}{}
\newcommand*{\M}{}
\newcommand*{\T}{}
\newcommand*{\SetupPlot}[5]{%
    \renewcommand*{\a}{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\g}{#2}%
    \renewcommand*{\kamax}{#3}%
    \renewcommand*{\M}{#4}%
    \renewcommand*{\T}{#5}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ra}{1 + \a*\M^(1-\g)/\kamax}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rb}{1 + \a*\M^(1-\g)/(4*\kamax)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\la}{\M/(2*\T*\Ra)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lb}{\M/(2*\T*\Rb)}%
}
```

The first lines just make sure the macors are not yet defined. You get an error message otherwise. `\def` will just overwrite the macros.

You can then write

```
\SetupPlot{1}{0.5}{5}{15}{3}
```

**Edit:**
I added `%` at the end of the lines in the definition of `\SetupPlot`, because, as cfr pointed out, if you use this macro outside a `tikzpicture` it will produce unwanted space without the `%`.

Comment: Not much point commenting the space at the beginning if you don't comment the rest.

Comment: @cfr you are right of course, but I got so accoustomed to this one (a lot of trouble in the past), I only start thinking about commenting spaces in the second line of a macro. And to my knowledge, inside TikZ it's not necessary.

Comment: The thing is that you macro doesn't have to be used inside a `tikzpicture`. I might use it to configure default settings outside such an environment.

Comment: @cfr you are right again.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked just fine. I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pgf/tikz keys to automatically set your variables. Since you are using `tikz` you might as well use `\tikzset`. All that you need to do is do define a key with a `code` handler and then have the code handler set all of your variables.

Here is one way to do this (as cfr says in the comments, the choice of variable names used here, following the OP, is unwise):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% only for \csuse in the MWE
\begin{document}

\tikzset{mysettings/.code n args={5}{% 5 arguments: \a, \g, \kamax, \M and \T
    \def\a{#1}% set the variables
    \def\g{#2}
    \def\kamax{#3}
    \def\M{#4}
    \def\T{#5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ra}{1 + \a*\M^(1-\g)/\kamax}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rb}{1 + \a*\M^(1-\g)/(4*\kamax)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\la}{\M/(2*\T*\Ra)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lb}{\M/(2*\T*\Rb)}
  }
}

\tikzset{mysettings={1}{0.5}{5}{15}{3}}
\foreach \var [count=\y]in {a,g,kamax,M,T,Ra,Rb,la,lb} {
  \var = \csuse{\var};
}

\tikzset{mysettings={2}{0.2}{1}{10}{-3}}
\foreach \var [count=\y]in {a,g,kamax,M,T,Ra,Rb,la,lb} {
  \var = \csuse{\var};
}

\end{document}
```

So I have defined the `tikz` key `mysettings` to take five arguments, corresponding to your parameters `\a`, `\g`, `\kamax`, `\M` and `\T` in this order. Passing these parameters to `mysettings` sets these five variables and, in addition, sets `\Ra`, `\Rb`, `\la` and `\lb`.

The for-loops at the end of the MWe are just to show that it works. The MWE produces:

[image]

Two more comments. You can also set your variables at the start of a `tikzicture` environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mysettings={1}{0.5}{5}{15}{3}]
....
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Rather than using `\def` in the definition of `mysettings` you might want to use `\gdef` in order to make the definitions "global". On the other hand, the code above makes then local which might be better in your use-case. As cfr says in the comments, this needs to be used with care.

Comment: It is extremely dangerous to use `\gdef` with these kinds of macro names. Please do not recommend this.

Comment: Following your advice would, for example, override LaTeX's definition of `\a` globally (`\a:
macro:#1->\expandafter \@changed@cmd \csname \string #1\endcsname \relax`) `. Are you sure that's wise?

Comment: @cfr It is true the macro names may break something but if this is the case then they will almost certainly break with `\def`, so `\gdef` is unlikely to cause more harm. Variable names always need to chosen with care and if the OP wants to use these who am I to say that they shouldn't?

Comment: The point is that the `\def`s are local to the `tikzpicture`. `\gdef`s will affect the whole document. So you are much more likely to break something with `\gdef`.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I agree, and that's exactly the point that I made in my post (global versus local) -- which, incidentally, does recommend using `\def`. I was giving the OP more information so that they would know what to do in the event they needed global variable. I am certainly not endorsing their choice of variable names. I think that it is good that you given additional information that they need to be careful with their variable names.

Comment: You're endorsing the names by posting them in your code. Even suggesting making them global is terrible advice. Especially since many users will have only the haziest of ideas, if any, about the difference between 'local' and 'global' and will likely have no idea about why the might not want to make the definitions global. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\a{1}
  \node {\a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\^{\a{i}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\a{1}
  \node {\a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\^{\a{i}}
\end{document}`

Comment: You can skip etoolbox with `\var = \csname\var\endcsname` and you don't need `;`

Comment: ah it's a separator nevermind

Comment: Yeah, I've just realized that there are some single-letter macros that already have a definition, and I should not redefine them. A list of those can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros, if you're curious.