# Command \p defined error but also undefined

Tags: macros, springernature

I am using the Springer nature latex template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq.

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, dsfont}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the the error message `./sn-article.tex:75: LaTeX Error: Command \p already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

However, if I call `$\p$` or `\p`, I get `./sn-article.tex:193: Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>` .

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to [Short names for macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros). but that shows it _should_ be undefined by default...

Comment: Off-topic: If `\E` is supposed to represent the expectations operator, it would be better to define it via `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}`. Here, I use "better" in the sense of improved spacing around the glyph that's generated by `\mathbb{E}`.

Comment: If you consult the error log closely, you'll see that it does *not* claim that `\p` is undefined. Instead, it says that `\p` (and its argument) must be executed in math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro -- or, at least, a macro that's defined via `\def`, `\newcommand`, or friends -- can't be simultaneously defined and undefined.

If I make your code snippet minimally compilable by prefixing it with `\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}` and affixing `\begin{document} \show\p \end{document}` to it, I get the following output (written to the screen and log file, but not to the pdf file):

```
> \p=macro:
#1->\mathrel {\ooalign {\hfil $\mapstochar \mkern 5mu$\hfil \cr $#1$}}.
l.23 \show\p
```

This macro takes one argument and should be used in math mode since its "outermost" constituent directive is `\mathrel`.

Aside: `\p` is not defined in the LaTeX kernel or in one of the standard LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, and `book`). Instead, `\p` is defined as part of the `sn-jnl` document class.

If you don't care about this macro and don't mind clobbering it -- warning: proceed at your own risk! -- you could simply replace

```
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}
```

However, clobbering existing macros is generally ill-advised. Do consider coming up with a name other than `\p` for the macro you intend to use in the body of your document.