# How to put the text and symbols "Italic" quickly?

Tags: macros, italic

The following is my original texts.

```
\textbf{The Interior Dirichlet Problem:} Given $f\in C(S)$, find
$u\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $u$ is harmonic on $\Omega$
and $u=f$ on $S$.
```

Instead of using `\emph{}` word by word and symbol by symbol, how can I quickly get everything *Italic* quickly?

---

I have tried the `\newtheorem` command. But the font would be different from the desired one. What's more, I am not able to get rid of the period automatically added by the macro.

Comment: You could apply one of the techniques proposed here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16996/1998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{problem}[1]
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
   \textbf{#1:}\em\ \ignorespaces}
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

...

\begin{problem}{The Interior Dirichlet Problem}
Given $f\in C(S)$, find $u\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ such
that $u$ is harmonic on $\Omega$ and $u=f$ on $S$.
\end{problem}
```

However, you can also put everything after the colon as argument to `\emph` or say `{\em Given $f\in C(S)$, ... on $S$.}`

Comment: I thought use of `\em` et al was discouraged?

Comment: @You: not at all. But it's preferable to use it only in the definition of environments. For a "one shot" application it's handier than a very long argument to `\emph`.

Comment: @You -- `\em` isn't the best command to use here, although it works.  `\itshape` is the preferred latex equivalent.