# How to treat specific words formatting (ie. API names to wrap inside texttt command)?

Tags: formatting, automation

I would like to know if there is any elegant way to treat specific words as symbols, and automatically wrap them with a `\texttt` command. This would come handy with API names for instance, so `\texttt` doesn't have to be added manually to every mention of the API.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your current setup that highlights the problem.

Comment: Minimal setup is \texttt wrapping around every mention of an API name. Nothing else. What I want is something at the beginning of the document that wraps them in texttt. Similar to the hyphenation command.

Comment: Are you hyphenating the API names? If so, I would create a macro for each API name. For example, `\newcommand{\MyMapApp}{\texttt{My\-Map\-App}}` that explicitly states the hyphenation for each API name.

Comment: When they are too long, yes. That looks awful in the long run. I will have more than a dozen separate commands and it does not make it much better for me. I want something more elegant than that. Think the way glossaries work, that might be a good example. Every acronym gets referenced.

Comment: @soze If you have solved your problem in the meantime, please share. Otherwise try providing some examples of what you need.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to have certain words in the document always in bold?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16996/3083). The question explores the similar problem of typesetting variable names in a book about a programming language. The answers explore several solutions.

Comment: With no clear example, this is 'too localized' I think. Ask for reopening if a nice clear demo can be given.