# Italicize all text in the body matching a pattern

Tags: emphasis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have certain words in the document always in bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16996/is-it-possible-to-have-certain-words-in-the-document-always-in-bold)

I have some old papers with a lot of references in it. I am converting them into LaTeX PDFs. I am not using any citation package here to style the references - it would be extremely painful and definitely not worth the effort to make the `.bib` file having all the old references. However, I would like to all of the `et al` in the text to be italicized.

The obvious approach would be to use the `\emph` the usual way for each instance of `et al`. But is there a faster/smarter way to achieve this? Some kind of pre-declaration in the preamble to automatically detect `et al` in the text and print them as italics?

Comment: I'd use the editor's search-and-replace function or some preprocessor (and a definition for `\etal` for example).

Comment: @RazorXsr: This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16996/is-it-possible-to-have-certain-words-in-the-document-always-in-bold. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: I've closed as a dupe: the core idea is similar to that in the post @doncherry linked to.