# coloring keywords in the whole document

Tags: color, text-decorations

Is there a way to color keywords into a document?

For instance, I want all the occurrences of a given word to appear in red in the whole document.

something like :

```
\colorize{red}{keywords={foo,bar}}
```

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [Is it possible to have certain words in the document always in bold?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16996)

Comment: You could (mis)use the [spelling](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spelling) package and put your keywords in `\jobname.spb`. Then set `\spellinghighlightcolor` to red. This only works with LuaLaTeX, though.

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate a little on my comment. You could use spelling with LuaLaTeX like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.spb}
foo
bar
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{spelling}

\begin{document}

Keyword foo in text.

Keyword bar in text.

\end{document}
```

This will highlight `foo` and `bar`. You'll need two compilations.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such way, the easiest would be to use search & replace. Using `LuaTeX` however it should be possible. I have seen a presentation about the `chickenize` package once which showed similar features. LuaTeX is able to hook into the text output before it is written to the PDF.

Here's a link to the German presentation PDF: http://www.dante.de/events/mv45/Programm/atrautmann/folien-trautmann.pdf

Comment: You could automate and vary  @UweZeigenhagen 's search & replace strategy with an `awk` (or `python` or ...) script that processed your `TeX` source prior to compilation.

Comment: It would be nice if you made your answer more complete, and included a simple example that does not rely on external sources. It is prefered on this site ;)

Comment: "Give the hungry a fish and he's fed for a while. Show him how to catch fish and he'll tell you he has better things to do than putting sticks in the water..." :-)
I have no experience with either the package or LuaTeX itself, so I can't provide an example. I just remembered the talk.