# How to color specific word in a paragraph more times?

Tags: macros, color, paragraphs, find

I have a paragraph with, let's say, 100 words, from which 10 of those words are the word "dokument". I want to make a command that colors that word in that paragraph. I'm including part of my code down below.

```
\begin{center}
\fontsize{17pt}{2}\selectfont TASK 1
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{70mm}

\bojenje{dokument}

Ovo je primjer centriranog \textbf{paragrafa} u okruženju
minipage čija je širina 70 mm. Unutar dokumenta
svaka instanca riječi dokument je obojena plavom bojom.
Možda da ne bi bilo loše napraviti komandu koja boji riječ
dokument plavom bojom?
Naslov dokumenta je font visine 17 pt.

\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. It's a little easier to start playing with your example and help you if you include a code-snipped that is compilable (i.e. includes `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, etc. and a minimal preable

Comment: okay, will note that in my future posts, thanks

Comment: By the way, you might want to add the line `\usepackage[croatian]{babel}` or `\usepackage[serbian-latin]{babel}` to get correct hyphenation. (Not sure which is more appropriate, sorry.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really possible with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`. See the related questions [automatic word in color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305681/automatic-word-in-color), [how to auto bold a keyword?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194527/how-to-auto-bold-a-keyword), [Is it possible to have certain words in the document always in bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16996/is-it-possible-to-have-certain-words-in-the-document-always-in-bold), where the advice is to define a macro (here that would be something like `\def\dokument{\textcolor{blue}{dokument}}` and then do search and replace in your editor to change all occurrences of `dokument` into `\dokument` (of course you can also skip the macro and search and replace `dokument` with `\textcolor{blue}{dokument}`). This would indeed be the easiest solution.

However, it can be done with LuaTeX, as noted in [Is it possible to have certain words in the document always in bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16996/is-it-possible-to-have-certain-words-in-the-document-always-in-bold). Things have changed a bit since 2011 so here is an updated version. The idea is to register a callback for processing the lines in your document, and use this callback to replace every occurrence of your target word with the same word as argument to `\textcolor{blue}`.

The simplest version with the word hardcoded and coloring for the whole document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{luacode}
    function translate(line)
        return string.gsub(line, "dokument", "\\textcolor{blue}{dokument}")
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", translate, "autocolor")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
Ovo je primjer centriranog \textbf{paragrafa} u okruženju
minipage čija je širina 70 mm. Unutar dokumenta
svaka instanca riječi dokument je obojena plavom bojom.
Možda da ne bi bilo loše napraviti komandu koja boji riječ
dokument plavom bojom?
Naslov dokumenta je font visine 17 pt.
\end{document}
```

For a bit of flexibility you can use some regular expression syntax to make sure the word is surrounded by word boundaries and to allow suffixes (here for example to color also the *a* in *dokumenta*. You can also activate and deactivate the callback with a separate command to be able to switch the automatic coloring on and off. Furthermore, you can make the replacement word a variable instead of hardcoding it in the `gsub` call.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{luacode}
    local myword = "init"

    local gsub = string.gsub
    function translate(line)
        wordpattern = "%f[%a]" .. myword .. "%a*%f[%A]"
        return gsub(line, wordpattern, "\\textcolor{blue}{%1}")
    end

    function setword(newword)
        myword = newword
    end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\startcoloring}[1]{\directlua{setword("#1")}%
\directlua{%
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", translate, "autocolor")}}

\newcommand\stopcoloring{\directlua{%
luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "autocolor")}}

\begin{document}
The word dokument is not colored.\\

\startcoloring{dokument}
Ovo je primjer centriranog \textbf{paragrafa} u okruženju
minipage čija je širina 70 mm. Unutar dokumenta
svaka instanca riječi dokument je obojena plavom bojom.
Možda da ne bi bilo loše napraviti komandu koja boji riječ
dokument plavom bojom?
Naslov dokumenta je font visine 17 pt.\\
\stopcoloring

Again dokument is not colored.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

To make it even more general you can create a list of target words (called `table` in Lua) and loop over all of them. Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{luacode}
    wordlist = {}

    local gsub = string.gsub
    function translatelist(line)
        for _, word in ipairs(wordlist) do
            wordpattern = "%f[%a]" .. word .. "%a*%f[%A]"
            line = gsub(line, wordpattern, "\\textcolor{blue}{%1}")
        end
        return line
    end

    function addword(newword)
        table.insert(wordlist,newword)
    end 
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\startcoloring}[1]{\directlua{%
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", translatelist, "autocolor")}}

\newcommand\stopcoloring{\directlua{%
luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "autocolor")}}

\begin{document}
The word dokument is not colored.\\

\directlua{addword("dokument")}
\directlua{addword("instanca")}
\startcoloring{}
Ovo je primjer centriranog \textbf{paragrafa} u okruženju
minipage čija je širina 70 mm. Unutar dokumenta
svaka instanca riječi dokument je obojena plavom bojom.
Možda da ne bi bilo loše napraviti komandu koja boji riječ
dokument plavom bojom?
Naslov dokumenta je font visine 17 pt.\\
\stopcoloring

Again dokument is not colored.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: wow I haven't expected such a thorough answer, thanks, this helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Just using pdflatex. EDITED to overcome the in-group limitation.  Now, this approach will find the word even when it is nested down in a group.

I also took the liberty of changing both the environment name (`\stain`) and the syntax, so that a specific `\endstain` call is needed to terminate the process.  I found that more logical and forgiving than requiring a closing `\par` to terminate.

The syntax is `\stain{<search term>}<paragraph material>\endstain`.  The `<search term>` cannot contain spaces.  The `<paragraph material>` can span multiple paragraphs.

The macro `\action` defines the manner in which matched terms are to be *stained*, and can be redefined at will.

The logic is as follows:  the `tokcycle` package is used to process the input paragraph (i.e., build a token list) as follows: every space is replaced with `\@sptoken`, so as not to interfere with later argument absorption in the `\checkfor` process.  If the first letter of the search term is found in the input stream, it is everywhere prepended with `\checkfor{}{<search term>}`.  This macro is defined to search subsequent tokens for the search term.  If the match fails, the partially matched tokens are merely output.  If the match is satisfied, `\action` is applied to the resulting match.

Once these substitutions are made, the revised token list is executed, to include the `\action` on matched terms.  `tokcycle` has the advantage of searching tokens inside groups (by default), so embedded copies of the search term are still found.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,xcolor}
\newcommand\action[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand\checkfor[3]{\checkforaux#3#2\relax\endchek{#1}}
\long\def\checkforaux#1#2#3\endchek#4{%
  \tctestifx{\relax#2}{\action{#4}#1}{%
    \tctestifx{#1#2}{\checkfor{#4#1}{#3}}{#4#1}}}
\makeatletter
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{\@sptoken}}
\makeatother
\long\def\stain#1{\stainaux#1\relax}
\long\def\stainaux#1#2\relax{%
 \Characterdirective{%
   \tctestifx{#1##1}{\addcytoks{\checkfor{}{#1#2}}}{}\addcytoks{##1}}%
 \let\endstain\endtokcycraw
 \tokencyclexpress\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\stain{document}
This is an example of a full-width \textbf{paragraph}. 
Inside this document's environment,
each instance of the word document is colored red.
Maybe it wouldn’t be bad to make a command that colors the word
document in blue?
The document has a font height of 10 pt. 
And, \textit{the stain can even find the word document inside groups}.  
How's that?
\endstain

\renewcommand\action[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\stain{do}
Whether do appears by itself, followed by chars as in
  door, or in \textit{the middle of a word do-bedobe-do, it all
  works} just so.
\endstain
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

One proviso is that the searched for word cannot exist in the context of a group (e.g., `\textit{...dokument...}`).  If one needs that, there many be a way, but it would be more complicated, so let me know.

The other proviso is there has to be an explicit end to the paragraph, that is, via a blank line or explicit `\par`, rather than just an end of group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listofitems}
\def\bojenje#1#2\par{%
  \setsepchar{#1}%
  \readlist\pardata{#2}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pardata[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\relax\else\textcolor{red}{#1}\fi
    \z
  }%
  \par
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{17pt}{2}\selectfont TASK 1
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{70mm}

\bojenje{dokument}
%
Ovo je primjer centriranog \textbf{paragrafa} u okruženju
minipage čija je širina 70 mm. Unutar dokumenta
svaka instanca riječi dokument je obojena plavom bojom.
Možda da ne bi bilo loše napraviti komandu koja boji riječ
dokument plavom bojom?
Naslov dokumenta je font visine 17 pt.

\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]